# Изменение элемента RecyclerView после загрузки данных с сервера Android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Всем привет.
У меня есть стандартный RecyclerView, куда я подгружаю данные с сервера (список новостей). Также прописана возможность ставить лайки для каждой новости. Когда пользователь ставит лайк, клиент отправляет данные на сервер и проверяет их. Если у пользователя есть права для выставления лайка, если он ещё не ставил лайк новости, сервер изменяет информацию в БД и возвращает код 200.
На данный момент я знаю, что можно менять отображение лайка сразу после клика в адаптере (регистрировать нажатие на кнопку в onBindViewHolder). Или добавлять элемент и менять отображение всего списка через `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

А можно ли каким-то образом изменить конкретный элемент из RecyclerView, после положительного ответа от сервера, предварительно записав position элемента?

Comment: Ты же сам ответил на свой вопрос. В holder'е объяви на каждый элемент setOnClickListener и сохраняй там position.

Comment: Да, я знаю как сохранить position) А как потом по position изменить элемент в RecyclerView?

Comment: Пробовал изменить массив данных по этому position и заново отправить в адаптер?

Comment: Меняю массив и обновляю весь список через adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Нет ли способа обновлять в адаптере один элемент, но не весь список?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких целей можно использовать `notifyItemChanged()`. Суть данного метода в том что вы можете изменить отображение конкретного элемента передав данному методу позицию нужного вам элемента. Например у вас есть условие что если ответ 200, то нужно изменить элемент:

```
if(response.code==200){

}
```

дальше внутрь этого блока следует поместить обновление нужного вам элемента. Но стоит учитывать что вам нужно знать какую позицию стоит обновить, поэтому в метод который отправляет данные на сервер нужно отправить и позицию нажатого вами элемента и вызывать метод:

```
notifyItemChanged(position, 0)
```

дальше в адаптере нужно переопределить метод который отвечает за обновление конкретного элемента. При вызове метода `notifyItemChanged(position, 0)` вы кроме позиции передаете грубо говоря идентификатор действия, то есть говорите например что поменять фон у картинки на зеленый так как ответ 200:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (!payloads.isEmpty()) {
        switch(payloads.get(0))
        {
           case 0:
             holder.textView.setText("200 response");
             break;

           case 1:
             holder.textView.setText("some error");
             break;


        }

    } else {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    }
}
```

в примере выше, вы при удачном ответе будете сетить в виджет элемента списка текст. В этом методе `holder` имеет доступ ко всем виджетам элемента списка, поэтому можете обновить то что вам нужно. Так же можно добавить какое-то действие если сервер вернет ошибку.

Comment: Использую Presenter для работы с сервером и проверки данных, не Adapter, но notifyItemChanged(position, 0) то, что нужно. Спасибо!)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, ещё одну вещь. С отправкой payloads всё получилось, ещё раз спасибо, но если я хочу отправить например два параметра, я пытаюсь это сделать через ArrayList: List<Object> loads = new ArrayList<>(); loads.add(likeStatus); loads.add(likes); как я могу получить доступ к первому и второму элементу? К первому вроде бы так: loads.get(0), но если ко второму пытаться loads.get(1), то появляется ошибка выхода за пределы массива. Пытался и приводить List<Object> к разным типам, но среде нужна именно такая перегрузка метода onBindViewHolder.

Comment: у меня некоторое время тому тоже возник такой вопрос, искал везде и спрашивал тоже, но несколько действий в один вызов впихнуть не смог к сожалению, как вариант можно сетить отдельный массив который будет вызываться при вызове payloads

Comment: Ок. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Хм. У меня получается добавить в Object из List две переменной и в логах они отображаются так: [[0, 1]]. Это объект, но как достать первый и второй элемент не пойму.

Comment: Да в логах все красиво, но когда дело доходит до адаптера вот тогда и начинаются сложности :(